# python 3.4 how to create a label

Tags: python-3.x, label

I am trying to create my first GUI. I have an error in my code below

```
name=label(text="this is a label")
```

this is the error message I get

```
NameError: name 'label' is not defined
```

can you help me please?

Comment: did you search the web?

Comment: I looked on tutorialspoint but it was to hard

Comment: Write `Label`. Python is case-sensitive.